# output for range not functioning live

Tags: html, forms, input, range, output

I have a feeling this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to discover what I am doing wrong.

I have a range slider on a site I am developing (http://psalfa.azurewebsites.net/members/newquotesuppliersearch.aspx) that is tied to an output element to display the value of the slider.

I got the code from a jsFiddle and tested it there to ensure it worked, however now that its on the site, the output is not changing.

The code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)">
    <input type="range" name="a" id="a" value="50" min="50" max="2500">
    <output name="x" id="x" for="a">50</output>
  </form>
```

Comment: I believe this is not working because the DOCTYPE of the page in question is HTML4, and not HTML5, to which this design belongs. Im not an expert though, so if someone with more than passing knowledge could provide this as an answer I would be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try: type="number" and add data-type="range"

Comment: I added these attributes to the output tag but it did not change anything.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Google Chrome and it is working fine. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Im looking at it in all browsers except i.e. and its not working in any of them. Are you looking at the link I provided?